# ScrollView doesn't scroll in NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've been trying to use NativeScript with Angular to create my first mobile application and have been doing pretty well so far. Recently though, I've ran into this problem where the page won't scroll to show me the rest of the page. I've re-created this in the Playground for you guys to see as well. I've tried changing the order that the ScrollView and StackLayouts are but I can't seem to figure out why it won't scroll. Here's the Playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=rNYOHR

Note: I'm on an iPhone 5S so some people out there with bigger phones might be able to see the whole thing, but I can't.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't use % for margin / padding, just numbers (that defaults to DIP - Density Independent Pixel) should give decent spacing on all screen ranges.

Comment: @Manoj ahhhh. interesting. that fixed the problem that I was having with spacing! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=rNYOHR&v=6). You have given height for the StackLayout in class and that is the culprit here.

```
.pageBackground{
    background-image: url('https://backgroundtown.com/content/images/thumbs/0002610_classic-texture-dark-cool-gray.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    /* height: 100% */
}

.main-container{
    /* height: 100%; */
    width: 100%;
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
}
```

P.S. I have tested on larger screen ios well.

Comment: this is awesome. is there any reason that this completely get rid of all of the vertical spacing that I had? before: https://imgur.com/FtVYPXT, after: https://imgur.com/JgshVuX

Comment: May be something to do with `form-control` class.